# How to replace a word instead of a string in emacs like this?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, I have the codes below:

```
(defun toggle-light ()
    "Toggle setting tab widths between 4 and 8"
    (setq a
      (if (boundp 'a) a nil))
    (interactive)
    (if a
    (progn
      (load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
      (setq a nil))
      (progn
    (load-theme 'solarized-light t)
    (setq a t) )))
```

And now I want to refactor this blocks by replacing the variable name `a` with `is-lighted`, but without changing other character `a` in other words (for example, in `interactive` or `tab`).

Is there a built-in function in emacs that can finsih that job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-%</kbd> `a` <kbd>RET</kbd> `is-lighted` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The prefix argument ("delimited") to the standard query-replace functions wraps the pattern with word-boundary markers.

Answer (score 1):

While [phils's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872617/596361) is correct and idiomatic, you should also learn about `\b` word boundary regular expression. Thus, equivalent regexp replace would be <kbd>M-%</kbd>`\ba\b`. See [Backslash in Regular Expressions @ Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) and [Regular Expression @ EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).